# expand data.frame to long format and increment value

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to convert my data from a short format to a long format and I imagine there is a simple way to do it (possibly with reshape2, plyr, dplyr, etc?).

For example, I have:

```
foo <- data.frame(id = 1:5, 
              y = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
              time = c(2, 3, 4, 2, 3))

id y time
1  0  2
2  1  3
3  0  4
4  1  2
5  0  3
```

I would like to expand/copy each row n times, where n is that row's value in the "time" column. However, I would also like the variable "time" to be incremented from 1 to n. That is, I would like to produce:

```
id  y time
1   0   1
1   0   2
2   1   1
2   1   2
2   1   3
3   0   1
3   0   2
3   0   3
3   0   4
4   1   1
4   1   2
5   0   1
5   0   2
5   0   3
```

As a bonus, I would also like to do a sort of incrementing of the variable "y" where, for those ids with y = 1, y is set to 0 until the largest value of "time". That is, I would like to produce:

```
id  y time
1   0   1
1   0   2
2   0   1
2   0   2
2   1   3
3   0   1
3   0   2
3   0   3
3   0   4
4   0   1
4   1   2
5   0   1
5   0   2
5   0   3
```

This seems like something that dplyr might already do, but I just don't know where to look. Regardless, any solution that avoids loops is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new data frame with the proper `id` and `time` columns for the long format, then merge that with the original.  This leaves `NA` for the unmatched values, which can then be substituted with `0`:

```
merge(foo, 
      with(foo, 
           data.frame(id=rep(id,time), time=sequence(time))
      ), 
      all.y=TRUE
)
##    id time  y
## 1   1    1 NA
## 2   1    2  0
## 3   2    1 NA
## 4   2    2 NA
## 5   2    3  1
## 6   3    1 NA
## 7   3    2 NA
## 8   3    3 NA
## 9   3    4  0
## 10  4    1 NA
## 11  4    2  1
## 12  5    1 NA
## 13  5    2 NA
## 14  5    3  0
```

A similar merge works for the first expansion.  Merge `foo` without the `time` column with the same created data frame as above:

```
merge(foo[c('id','y')], 
      with(foo, 
           data.frame(id=rep(id,time), time=sequence(time))
      )
) 
##    id y time
## 1   1 0    1
## 2   1 0    2
## 3   2 1    1
## 4   2 1    2
## 5   2 1    3
## 6   3 0    1
## 7   3 0    2
## 8   3 0    3
## 9   3 0    4
## 10  4 1    1
## 11  4 1    2
## 12  5 0    1
## 13  5 0    2
## 14  5 0    3
```

It's not necessary to specify `all` (or `all.y`) in the latter expression because there are multiple `time` values for each matching `id` value, and these are expanded.  In the prior case, the `time` values were matched from both data frames, and without specifying `all` (or `all.y`) you would get your original data back.

Answer (score 3):

The initial expansion can be achieved with:

```
newdat <- transform( 
  foo[rep(rownames(foo),foo$time),], 
  time = sequence(foo$time)
)

#    id y time
#1    1 0    1
#1.1  1 0    2
#2    2 1    1
#2.1  2 1    2
#2.2  2 1    3
# etc
```

To get the complete solution, including the bonus part, then do:

```
newdat$y[-cumsum(foo$time)] <- 0

#    id y time
#1    1 0    1
#1.1  1 0    2
#2    2 0    1
#2.1  2 0    2
#2.2  2 1    3
#etc
```

If you were really excitable, you could do it all in one step using `within`:

```
within(
  foo[rep(rownames(foo),foo$time),],
  {
    time <- sequence(foo$time)
    y[-cumsum(foo$time)] <- 0
  }
)
```

Comment: @MatthewLundberg - the `cumsum(foo$time)` will always give the last row of the groups in the expanded data. Subsetting that for `y==1` and inverting it sets all rows before the final row in each group to 0.

Comment: +1.  I didn't take any measurements, but this looks to be more efficient than a merge.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, well, with a "dplyr" and "data.table" solution in the options now, who's going to do the benchmarking ;-)

Comment: Actually, with some quick tests, this performs very well.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to go with "data.table", you can try:

```
library(data.table)
fooDT <- as.data.table(foo)
fooDT[, list(time = sequence(time)), by = list(id, y)]
#     id y time
#  1:  1 0    1
#  2:  1 0    2
#  3:  2 1    1
#  4:  2 1    2
#  5:  2 1    3
#  6:  3 0    1
#  7:  3 0    2
#  8:  3 0    3
#  9:  3 0    4
# 10:  4 1    1
# 11:  4 1    2
# 12:  5 0    1
# 13:  5 0    2
# 14:  5 0    3
```

And, for the bonus question:

```
fooDT[, list(time = sequence(time)), 
      by = list(id, y)][, y := {y[1:(.N-1)] <- 0; y}, 
                        by = id][]
#     id y time
#  1:  1 0    1
#  2:  1 0    2
#  3:  2 0    1
#  4:  2 0    2
#  5:  2 1    3
#  6:  3 0    1
#  7:  3 0    2
#  8:  3 0    3
#  9:  3 0    4
# 10:  4 0    1
# 11:  4 1    2
# 12:  5 0    1
# 13:  5 0    2
# 14:  5 0    3
```

For the bonus question, alternatively:

```
fooDT[, list(time=seq_len(time)), by=list(id,y)][y == 1, 
                y := c(rep.int(0, .N-1L), 1), by=id][]
```

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr (and magritte for nice legibility):

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

foo[rep(1:nrow(foo), foo$time), ] %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(y = !duplicated(y, fromLast = TRUE),
                  time = 1:n())
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You could try `foo[rep(1:nrow(foo), foo$time),] %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(time=1:n(), y=replace(y, !!y, c(rep(0, n()-1), 1)))`